# Read data from read only xlsm file using Java Apache POI

Tags: java, file-io, apache-poi, xlsx

I'm trying to read data from a read only xlsm using java apache poi, but when I use XSSF workbook it doesn't seem to be able to access the file and HSSF workbooks only work for xls files. My code looks like this:

```
try {
                FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("file.xlsm"));
                System.out.println("found file");
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
                System.out.println("in workbook");
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Shipments");
                System.out.println("got sheet");
```

The code never reaches the "in workbook" print line and I'm not sure why. Please help!

Comment: What exception gets thrown?

Comment: none, the program just keeps running but never does anything

Comment: @ajs this sounds like you actually catch and swallow the exception. I'm interested on what is in your catch block...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I copied your code and gave the ***absolute path*** of the file, and I was able to get the expected result.

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\filet.xlsm"));
System.out.println("found file");
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
System.out.println("in workbook");
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Shipments");
System.out.println("got sheet");
```

It seems like a problem with your referencing. Therefore *check the way you refer to the files when you try to create the file resource*.

Comment: the file I'm accessing is a network file, do you think that would cause the problem?

Comment: I tried the same code and i ma getting following java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException. Please help me out if you have any clue

Comment: @user1047873 - Is xmlbeans-2.X.X.jar in your classpath?

Answer (score 4):

Version 4.0.0 has a workbook factory class with a boolean "readonly" parameter.
So, to open in read-only mode...

```
XSSFWorkbook nextWorkbook = XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(myFile, true);
```