# How to read and append a .xlsm file in java

Tags: java, file, xlsm

I want to read and append a .xlsm file in java. I dont have any idea on how to do it. 
Do i need to download any jar file to work with it? 
All the search result provides a solution which uses apache poi(I did not get what it is). I dont use any IDE. Using simple FileReader and other logic can't I work with this type of file?

Please give me a clear idea on what is a .xlsm file and how to work with it using java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"XLSM is a Microsoft Excel macro-enabled spreadsheet that contains worksheets of cells arranged by rows and columns and embedded macros programmed in the Visual Basic for Applications language. XLSM files are like XLSX files, but with macros enabled. They can be opened with Excel 2007 or later, or by previous versions of Excel with Open XML component support."

You can read and write to the file using Apache poi.

**Take a look at the following SO Posts**

[write to xlsm (Excel 2007) using apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350178/write-to-xlsm-excel-2007-using-apache-poi)

[Read data from read only xlsm file using Java Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24317688/read-in-from-read-only-xlsm-file-using-java-apache-poi)

The Apache POI documentation is located at 
https://poi.apache.org/